# Spring JPA More than one row with given identifier

Tags: spring, database, hibernate, cascade

I have tried other solutions for this problem, alas the problem still exists. This is the error:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1, for class: CO3102.hw2.domain.records
> at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
> at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.loadByUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
> at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:692) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
> at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:154) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]

What I have been doing:
I have a record class, with name, vaccine id, dosage etc. I am saving a vaccine row into this Vaccine ID section, but now when I add more users I get the error above. I have tried following many solutions on here but they don't work for me, so if anyone could help please. Here is my records class. The other solutions talked about adding fetch.type = lazy which I have done which still makes the error present itself.

Record class

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name ="Vaccine_vaccineID")
private Vaccine vaccine;
```

The vaccine class

```
@Id
String vaccineID;
String Name;
VaccineType type;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "vaccine")
private records record;
```

I'll explain the problem again, so there is 2 possible vaccines (a,b) and these have ID's of 1 and 2. So obviously I want multiple users to have the same id for the vaccine. Am I doing this the wrong way - should I just save a number 1 in the place of this instead of actually saving the row?

If anyone could provide me with a solution to this problem I would be very appreciative. Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to achieve is many-to-one relationship.
Try the following:

**Record**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name ="Vaccine_vaccineID")
private Vaccine vaccine;
```

**Vaccine**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "vaccine")
private List<Record> records;
```

Comment: Thank you sir! You have saved me thank you :)